# Convert code from Spacy2 to Spacy3 - nlp.update not working

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

*Edit: Thanks for the comment. I changed doc= nlp(text) to doc = nlp.make_doc(text).*

I found a code that I am trying to replicate. It was apparently written in Spacy2:

```
# add NER to the pipeline and the new label
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
ner.add_label("FOOD")

# get the names of the components we want to disable during training
pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]

# start the training loop, only training NER
epochs = 30
optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes), warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("once", category=UserWarning, module='spacy')
    sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)
    
    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatc
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        examples = TRAIN_DATA
        random.shuffle(examples)
        batches = minibatch(examples, size=sizes)
        losses = {}
        
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)

        print("Losses ({}/{})".format(epoch + 1, epochs), losses)
```

Now the texts and annotations is not accepted in Spacy3 anymore. So I tried to convert like following (after already many desperate attempts):

```
import de_core_news_lg
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_lg')
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
ner.add_label("LOCALITY")
from spacy.training import Example
from spacy.tokens import Doc


# get the names of the components we want to disable during training
pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]

# start the training loop, only training NER
epochs = 30
optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
#optimizer = nlp.initialize()
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes), warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("once", category=UserWarning, module='spacy')
    sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)
    
    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatc
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        #text = []
        #annots=[]
        examples=[]


        for text,annots in TRAIN_DATA:
            #text.append(t)
            #annots.append(a)
            doc = nlp.make_doc(text)    
            example = Example.from_dict(doc, annots)
            examples.append(example)
        
        losses = {}
        
        nlp.update(examples, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)

        print("Losses ({}/{})".format(epoch + 1, epochs), losses)
```

And now the error is

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-8337234c4d53> in <module>
     36         losses = {}
     37 
---> 38         nlp.update(examples, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)
     39 
     40         print("Losses ({}/{})".format(epoch + 1, epochs), losses)

~/nlp_learn/statbot/.statbot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/language.py in update(self, examples, _, drop, sgd, losses, component_cfg, exclude)
   1104             if name in exclude or not hasattr(proc, "update"):
   1105                 continue
-> 1106             proc.update(examples, sgd=None, losses=losses, **component_cfg[name])
   1107         if sgd not in (None, False):
   1108             for name, proc in self.pipeline:

~/nlp_learn/statbot/.statbot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/transition_parser.pyx in spacy.pipeline.transition_parser.Parser.update()

~/nlp_learn/statbot/.statbot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/transition_parser.pyx in spacy.pipeline.transition_parser.Parser.get_batch_loss()

~/nlp_learn/statbot/.statbot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/ner.pyx in spacy.pipeline._parser_internals.ner.BiluoPushDown.set_costs()

ValueError:
```

Valuerror is empty. I've read that this could be connected to small samples? But there are over 5900 items now in examples. I'm trying to use a german model (de_core_news_lg).

Creating the "Example" he also gives now this warning in a loop:

```
/home/z01/nlp_learn/statbot/.statbot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/training/iob_utils.py:139: UserWarning: [W030] Some entities could not be aligned in the text "Was ist der Anteil an Bevölkerung: Anteil 80 u.m.-..." with entities "[(62, 70, 'GRAN')]". Use `spacy.training.offsets_to_biluo_tags(nlp.make_doc(text), entities)` to check the alignment. Misaligned entities ('-') will be ignored during training.
```

Comment: Please try replacing `doc = nlp(text) ` with `doc = nlp.make_doc(text) `

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue through the new generated warnings thanks to the comment by krisograbek after correcting nlp.make_doc(text).

The was the minus-symbol (-) in the strings. After replacing them at the right place with sentence=sentence.replace("-","") everything works!